# For loop of appended dictionaries in Python Flask template

Tags: flask

I'm trying to get multiple items to display in my Flask shopping cart. I want to append the list of product dictionaries in `cart_list` to a new list of all cart dictionaries in `append_list`, and display the `append_list` values in my Flask template in cart.html.

- **How do I parse the values from the new "appended" dictionaries list in `append_list`?**  Would appreciate any help (please)!! (Stripped out my variables (below) with static values for testing purposes.)

### Flask code

```
@app.route('/<int:id>/cart', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_to_cart(id):
    tag = get_tag(id)

    try:
        product_quantity = 300
        user_quantity = 10

        if user_quantity > product_quantity:
            flash("Please enter a lower quantity.")
            return render_template('tag.html', tag=tag)

        else:
            tag_id = 12
            product = "Title"
            price = 300
            sub_total = "{:.2f}".format( user_quantity * price )
            price = "{:.2f}".format(price)

            json = {
                "id": tag_id,
                "product": product,
                "price": price,
                "user-quantity": user_quantity,
                "product-quantity": product_quantity,
                "subtotal": sub_total
            }

            cart_list = []
            cart_list.append(json)
            append_list = []
            for item in cart_list:
                ele = item 
                append_list.append(ele)
                print(append_list)

                
            flash("Added to cart.")
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.args)

    return render_template('cart.html', tag=tag, sub_total=sub_total, cart_list=cart_list, append_list=append_list)
```

### Json I need

User adds item to cart, add to `append_list`.

```
append_list = [
{
    "id": tag_id,
    "product": product,
    "price": price,
    "user-quantity": user_quantity,
    "product-quantity": product_quantity,
    "subtotal": sub_total
},
{
    "id": tag_id,
    "product": product,
    "price": price,
    "user-quantity": user_quantity,
    "product-quantity": product_quantity,
    "subtotal": sub_total
}
]
```

etc.

### cart.html

Currently my code in cart.html is successfully parsing only one product dictionary (`cart_list.append(json)`). I keep erroring out when parsing dictionary values from `append_list`.

```
  {% for item in cart_list %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ cart_list[0]['product'] }}</td>
      <td>{{ cart_list[0]['price'] }}</td>
      <td>{{ cart_list[0]['user-quantity'] }}</td>
      <td>{{ cart_list[0]['subtotal'] }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```